# one way encryption oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

is there a way to do one way encryption for password in oracle? i'm passing in password from a textfield and would like to call a stored procedure in oralce and inside that stored procedure, it would encrypt the password. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption is, by definition, two-way.  You would never encrypt a password.  I expect that you really want to hash the password.  And you wouldn't want to just hash the password, you'd really want to combine the password with some sort of random salt and hash that.

You'd use the [`dbms_crypto.hash` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#i1002022) to compute the hash and the [`dbms_random.string` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996825) to generate the salt.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_salt           varchar2(50);
  l_user           varchar2(50);
  l_pwd            varchar2(50);
  l_string_to_hash varchar2(150);
  l_hash           raw(150);
BEGIN
  l_salt := dbms_random.string( 'P', 50 );
  l_string_to_hash := l_user || l_pwd || l_salt;
  l_hash := dbms_crypto.hash( utl_i18n.string_to_raw( l_string_to_hash, 'AL32UTF8' ), 
                              dbms_crypto.hash_sh1 );
END;
```

See also [this askTom discussion](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:95412348059) (which starts off using the older `dbms_obfuscation_toolkit` package rather than the `dbms_crypto` package) for more background on why you'd use a hash, the benefits of salting the password, etc.

Comment: i got dbms_crypto must be declared. is it because i'm using 10g?

Comment: @user3731575 - `dbms_crypto` exists in 10.2.  I'm pretty sure it existed in 10.1 as well (though that's been desupported so long, memory fades).  You may need your DBA to grant you access to that package.

Comment: so dbms_crypto is not supported in 11g or later version? is there anything i can use in 10g and later version? since my company is migrating to 11g soon. thanks

Comment: @user3731575 - Sorry, I don't follow you.  I said 10.1 has been desupported for a long time.  10.2 has been desupported for a while.  `dbms_crypto` certainly exists in 10.2 and later.  I'm pretty sure it exists in 10.1 but, as I said, that version is old enough that I don't quite recall.  `dbms_obfuscation_toolkit` is even older, going back to the 8i days, and still works going forward though it's not the preferred solution.